# How to identify the clients in SSL in order to use symetric keys?

Tags: ssl

I was going to HTTPS communication over SSL. What I understood is both client and server do the handshake to obtain symmetric keys for application data encryption and decryption.
My doubt is when a client sends a piece of encrypted data to server then how the server will identify the client and use the corresponding keys for decryption?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's the client's IP address and ephemeral port number that identify the connection to the application.

Answer (score 0):

The SSL/TLS handhsake happens between the client and the server. At the end of the handshake, the client and the server will have established shared keys (and MAC secrets to ensure the integrity of the communication). In case of session resumption, a session identifier can be used to associate further connections with the same key.

The rest of the connection is identified using the normal TCP mechanism (assuming SSL/TLS over TCP).